# Jquery slide - auto slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, slide

my jquery slide:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 10000);
  });

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 600, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 600, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

my jquery slider will automatically slide. what should I adjust this?
I have already installed a checkbox. is that too without checkbox?

Comment: you want to slide on dom ready, like, without checking the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

  $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

  $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

  function moveLeft() {
      $('#slider ul').animate({
          left: + slideWidth
      }, 600, function () {
          $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
          $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
      });
  };

  function moveRight() {
      $('#slider ul').animate({
          left: - slideWidth
      }, 600, function () {
          $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
          $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
      });
  };

  $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
      moveLeft();
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function () {
      moveRight();
  });

  setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
  }, 10000);

});
```